# Dataset row count to textbox

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I've got a `DataSet` in C# in which I have a row count to `textbox9` but I would like to filter it so that it only counts where the `Status='Closed'`. I can do this using a SQL statement before it goes to the `DataSet` but I want to put all the data into a single `DataSet` and then just filter that instead.

```
MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CR$]'", MyConnection);
DataSet dtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
MyCommand.Fill(dtSet);
bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = dtSet;
bindingSource1.DataMember = dtSet.Tables[0].TableName;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
textBox9.Text = dtSet.Tables[0].Select("Status='Closed'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = dtSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Status='Closed'";
```